# How to protect timestamp column from user update

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I created a trigger to place two timestamps, inserted and updated.  I want the created timestamp to be frozen forever, but I found that the user can update it directly  (after normal insert) with a regular SQL UPDATE statement.  How can I protect the tsCreated from user update?

Here is the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AAAjob_timing
    before insert or update
    on AAAJOB
    for each row
begin
    CASE
        WHEN INSERTING THEN
            :new.tsCreated := sysdate;
            :new.tsUpdated := :new.tsCreated;
        WHEN UPDATING THEN
            :new.tsUpdated := sysdate;
    END CASE; 
    end;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise an exception in your trigger when user attempts to update value in this column.

Comment: Make this a constraint (after update) and install it as a user (sysadmin for example) that the normal user can't become, at least not with ease

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AAAJOB_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON AAAJOB
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    :NEW.TSCREATED := SYSDATE;
    :NEW.TSUPDATED := SYSDATE;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    :NEW.TSCREATED := :OLD.TSCREATED;
    :NEW.TSUPDATED := SYSDATE;
  ENDIF;
END AAJOB_TRIGGER;
```

Share and enjoy.